# C++ class getter not returning any value in main, but does in the class?

Tags: c++, variables, setter, getter, public

I am hoping someone can point me in the direction, why my getter function cannot seem to be accessed properly when it is used outside the function in which the setter is declared.

I am reading in a file, storing variables of each line using the getline function, and then assigning the message to a private variable in **Message.h**.

When I cout the `m1.getmessage()` in within the `readfile()` function it outputs absolutely fine, with the correct output (The message line from my text file), however it j**ust gives blank output** in the `main()`. I've been trying to get my head around it for quite a few hours now, I have been reading about local variables but as far as I can see the variable is already set, and in a public function, therefore I can't see where I'm going wrong. Any help would be really appreciated before I reach for the vino at 4am.

**Message.h**

```
#include <iostream>

class Message {
private:
std::string message;
std::string cipher;


public:
    void readFile();

    void setMessage(std::string msg) {
        message = msg;
    }
    void setCipher(std::string ciph) {
        cipher = ciph;
    }

    std::string getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    std::string getCipher() {
        return cipher;
    }
};
```

**Message.cpp**

```
#include "Message.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void Message::readFile()    {
    std::string fileUsername;
    std::string fileForename;
    std::string fileSurname;
    std::string fileAge;
    std::string fileTime;
    std::string fileHour;
    std::string fileMin;
    std::string fileSec;
    std::string fileCipher;
    std::string fileMessage;
    Message m1;
    std::fstream file;
    std::string filename;
    std::cout << "Please enter file name: " << std::endl;
    getline(std::cin, filename);
    file.open(filename);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "File opened" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Wrong file name" << std::endl;
    }
    while(file.is_open()) {

        getline(file, fileUsername);
        getline(file, fileForename);
        getline(file, fileSurname);
        getline(file, fileAge);
        getline(file, fileHour, ':');
        getline(file, fileMin, ':');
        getline(file, fileSec);
        getline(file, fileCipher);
        getline(file, fileMessage);
        file.close();
    }
    m1.setMessage(fileMessage);
    m1.setCipher(fileCipher);
    m1.getMessage();

};
```

**Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include "Message.h"
#include "Caesar.h"
#include "XOR.h"


int main() {

    Message m1;
    m1.readFile();
    std::cout << m1.getMessage();


    return 0;
}
```

The cout in the main is returning nothing, whereas if I transfer it into m1.readfile() it outputs the variable perfectly.

This is my first attempt at object orientated programming and it's definitely my weak spot. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: No, don't edit the correct code into the question! It will confuse future readers. Instead, *accept* an answer that explains how to fix the code by pressing the green tick on the left of that answer. You can only accept one answer, so pick one that helped you the most. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Message::readFile()` function, you are not calling the functions `setMessage` and `setCipher` on the current object, but on a local variable m1. The local variable is discarded at end of the function and the message and cipher don't end up getting saved. You should instead just call

```
setMessage(fileMessage);
setCipher(fileCipher);
getMessage();
```

instead of

```
m1.setMessage(fileMessage);
m1.setCipher(fileCipher);
m1.getMessage();
```

This will update the message and cipher variables of the current object and you can then print `getMessage()` from the `main` function.

Answer (score 0):

you create a local variable m1 in readfile. And then it gets discarded when the function ends. Probably you want to either return the object, or set the current instance

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create an object inside that class's member function

My suggestion:

- Omit / Remove `Message m1;` in the `readFile()`
- Directly call the fuctions as

  `setMessage(fileMessage);` 
  `setCipher(fileCipher);`
  `getMessage();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **this**; pointer to object that your currently working on.
like below.

```
this->setMessage(fileMessage);
```

or

```
(*this).setMessage(fileMessage);
```

Comment: It's unnecessary, OP could simply do `setMessage(fileMessage);`.

Comment: understood, just showing OP another way to do it. but your right it's unnecessary...